# In a table which is data bound using knockout how to dynamically select any column values from view model

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I've a view model which I am binding to the view-
JSFiddle link to the code- http://jsfiddle.net/piyush4bpl/9kq2t5xu/

In the view model, I've two arrays-
grid, kpis

I am binding 'kpis' in to drop downs options. 'grid' is an array which has 4 properties named as 'Promoters', 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Neutral'. 'kpis' which is bound with 4 dropdowns also has same options- 'Promoters', 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Neutral'.

My requirement is to dynamically bind any property(positive,negative,neutral,negative) to any column based on the selection in its columns dropdown.

For example- If in the 3rd column, dropdown is selected as Negative, then the same column should show only 'Negative' property values from grid array in same column. If I change the dropdown to Neutral then only neutrals should  be shown.

HTML-

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td> Question Id</td>
        <td> Question Text</td>
        <td><select id="kpiddl" data-bind="options: kpi, optionsText: 'KpiName', optionsValue: 'KpiValue', value: 1"></select></td>
        <td><select id="kpiddl" data-bind="options: kpi, optionsText: 'KpiName', optionsValue: 'KpiValue', value: 2"></select></td>
        <td><select id="kpiddl" data-bind="options: kpi, optionsText: 'KpiName', optionsValue: 'KpiValue', value: 3"></select></td>
        <td><select id="kpiddl" data-bind="options: kpi, optionsText: 'KpiName', optionsValue: 'KpiValue', value: 4"></select></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--ko foreach:tags-->
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: QuestionId"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: QuestionText"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Positive"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Negative"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Neutral"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Promoters"></td>            
    </tr>
    <!--/ko-->
</tbody>
</table>
```

viewmodel-

```
$(function () {
var grid = [
    { QuestionId: 1, QuestionText: "Why did you give that rating for likelihood to recommend?", Positive:5, Negative:8,Neutral:18,Promoters:85 },
           { QuestionId: 2, QuestionText: "Passing", Positive:5, Negative:8,Neutral:18,Promoters:85 },
           { QuestionId: 3, QuestionText: "Shooting", Positive:6, Negative:9,Neutral:78,Promoters:80 },
           { QuestionId: 4, QuestionText: "Rebounding", Positive:67, Negative:4,Neutral:10,Promoters:15 },
           { QuestionId: 5, QuestionText: "Transition", Positive:18, Negative:48,Neutral:14,Promoters:33 },
           { QuestionId: 6, QuestionText: "Defense", Positive:74, Negative:74,Neutral:45,Promoters:46 },
           { QuestionId: 7, QuestionText: "Team Offense", Positive:5, Negative:8,Neutral:18,Promoters:85 },
           { QuestionId: 8, QuestionText: "Team Defense", Positive:5, Negative:8,Neutral:18,Promoters:85 }
];

var kpis = [
    {KpiName: "Promoters", KpiValue: 1},
    {KpiName: "Positive", KpiValue: 2},
    {KpiName: "Negative", KpiValue: 3},
    {KpiName: "Neutral", KpiValue: 4}
];


 var viewModel = {
    tags: ko.observableArray(grid),

    kpi: ko.observableArray(kpis)

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: i don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. do you want to change the selected values of the dropdowns when a selection is changes or do you want to filter the data in the table?

Comment: @Tanner- When I change a dropdown selection to say 'Positive' then in that column, I want to bind 'Positive' property values from object named as 'Grid'. I can again change the selection for same dropdown to 'Negative' then values, which property name is 'Negative', in the object 'Grid', should be bound to the same column. That means, When I change dropdown on top of any column, then according to selection, the same column changes it's values.

Comment: @peeyush i will do it for  a single column try implementing for other columns check here http://jsfiddle.net/9kq2t5xu/1/ . cheers

Comment: @supercool Your solutions worked for me. Please post it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to do a conditional check in view and make everything observable using `mapping plugin` .

Please check the below code implementation for `column 1`

**View :**

```
 <td data-bind="text:  $parent.selectOne() == 1 ?  $data.Promoters : $parent.selectOne() == 2 ? $data.Positive : $parent.selectOne() == 3 ? $data.Negative : $data.Neutral "></td>
```

**viewModel:**

```
 var viewModel = function (){
         var self=this;
        self.tags= ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.fromJS(data1)()); 
        self.kpi= ko.observableArray(kpis);
        self.selectOne=ko.observable(); //used for column1 dropdown selection
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Refer complete code in fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9kq2t5xu/1/)**